# Atari 400 membrane keyboard or similar flat keyboard lacking physical keys

Tags: keyboards

I don’t think I’m going to be able to buy this, tried numerous searches. it comes very close to what I have been looking for, for many years.

#### Atari 400 membrane keyboard

Here it is suggested by a user on my last post.

[Atari 400 keyboard](https://www.the-liberator.net/site-files/retro-games/hardware/Atari-400/Rev-1-16K/Atari-400-Rev-1-16K-034-Keyboard.JPG)

I made a previous post about keyless flat keyboards

[previous post](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16370/flat-keyboard-without-any-physical-keys/16377?noredirect=1#comment26805_16377)

Settled for the 'purekeys compact keyboard' which is allegedly worth $199 but I got it for £30. It is very nice, but not my ideal.

I confirmed it's genuine by sending pictures to the manufacturer.

#### Criteria

- No glass keyboards unless they are rectangular.
- Completely flat keys, no raised bumps.
- Preferable completely stiff/hard keys, although not so important.
- I already have the purekeys medical keyboard so don't need any advise on that.
- No laser keyboard unless there is a way to project the laser on a rectangular piece of glass or rectangular glass which just has key letters as light/leds.

#### Notes

This is a very pleasant community, glad to be here.

Comment: Not an answer because this is not an answer, it's a not -there item. Video from 8 years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IrZQzINF6U
A different product listed similar, but request for quote means expensive: https://www.blue-line.com/products/cleanroom-hmi-workstation/cleanroom-touch-keyboard

Comment: seems like a medical keyboard which I just got, yes they're very expensive